# Blazor WASM the uses Cosmos DB instead of SQL for Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, azure-cosmosdb, blazor-webassembly

Does anyone know of a Blazor Web Assembly Template that uses Cosmos Db instead of SQL for Identity?

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor WebAssembly, is there no way to connect to the DB? Not directly. Blazor WebAssembly is a front end framework. You need to create an API controller to wrap your database connection and use HttpClient to call the api. for better understanding please check the link given below.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5268083/EF-Core-and-Cosmos-DB-with-Blazor-WebAssembly